# C memcmp third parameter type

Tags: c++, c, parameters, sizeof, memcmp

Third argument in memcmp should be of type sizeof(). I read this code with the following

```
memcmp(st.magic, "outpt_01",sizeof(st.magic)) == 0 && st.version == 0 )
```

where `st` is a struct.

What is the type of the third parameter in the call above? what is it doing ?

Comment: The type of the third argument is `std::size_t` (see e.g. [this `memcmp` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp)), which is exactly what [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) gives you. Could you please elaborate more on what problem you have?

Comment: Oh, and unless the size of `st.magic` is equal or smaller than 9 bytes, the `memcmp` call will read data out of bounds of the string literal, and you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: For clarification, can you please show the *complete* statement where the call is in? Because right now you have more closing parentheses than opening.

Comment: If you don't have an IDE with builtin help, that's pretty well documented online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the type of the third parameter in the call above?

`size_t` Number of bytes to compare.

what is it doing ?

```
if (sizeof(st.magic) == 0 && st.version == 0)
    memcmp(st.magic, "outpt_01", 1);
else
    memcmp(st.magic, "outpt_01", 0);
```

As pointed out by @JoachimPileborg, there is a typo in:

```
memcmp(st.magic, "outpt_01",sizeof(st.magic)) == 0 && st.version == 0 )
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------^ extra closing parenthesis

or it is part of a condition like (makes more sense):

```
if (memcmp(st.magic, "outpt_01",sizeof(st.magic)) == 0 && st.version == 0) {
```

Comment: No, that's not what's happening (unless the OP added an extra closing parenthesis by mistake). Instead it looks to be part of a condition, and checks if `memcmp` returns zero or not.